# Uniform convergence of logarithm on a compact set.

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity, logarithms, compactness, uniform-convergence

Given that $\phi$ and $\phi_n,n \geq 1$ are continuous functions from $\mathbb{R}$ into $\mathbb{C}$ such that $ \phi(0) = \phi_n(0) = 1$, $\phi(x) \neq 0$ and $\phi_n(x) \neq 0$ for any $x$. Suppose that for any compact subset $K$ of $\mathbb{R}$ $$ \lim_{n\to \infty} \sup_{x \in K} \vert \phi(x) - \phi_n(x) \vert = 0. $$ Does this imply that $$ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}: \lim_{n \to \infty} \log \phi_n(x) = \log \phi(x)$$?

Comment: No, because the $\log$ function cannot be continuous on $\mathbb C \setminus \{0\}$ -- in particular you can take $\phi, \phi_n$ to be constant mappings. But for someone to give you a counterexample you will need to specify "which" $\log$ on $\mathbb C \setminus \{0\}$ you mean.

Comment: Err, forget the point about constant mappings. That's not true with the condition that $\phi(0) = \phi_n(0) = 1$. You can use a locally constant mapping with value at the a discontinuity of $\log$.

Comment: I choose to define $\log(z) = \log(|z|) + i arg(z) with -\pi < arg(z) \leq \pi